# Geopy Error with Reverse Geocoding

Tags: python, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I am using Geopy. I get the following error for the code.

I have using the same code as on https://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/ReverseGeocoding

```
from geopy import geocoders

g = geocoders.GeoNames()
(place, point) = g.geocode("Palo Alto, CA 94306")
print place
>> "Palo Alto, US 94306"
print point
>> (37.418008999999998, -122.127375)

(new_place,new_point) = g.reverse(point)
print new_place
>> 3998 Ventura Ct, Palo Alto, US 94306 
print new_point
>> (37.417850000000001, -122.12793000000001)
```

Works fine till print point. Error occurs with `g.reverse(point)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 9, in reverse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also posted on gis.se: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59216/geopy-error-with-reverse-geocoding

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding available on geopy 0.97. You can download and install new version of geopy from https://github.com/geopy/geopy or clone the git repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/geopy/geopy.git
cd geopy
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you want to download and install for windows, you can get a latest version from https://github.com/geopy/geopy/archive/release-0.97.zip

Unzip and

```
cd geopy-release-0.97
python setup.py install
```

To geolocate a query to an address and coordinates:

```py
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3()
>>> address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
>>> print(address, latitude, longitude)
175 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10010, USA 40.7410262 -73.9897806
```

To find the address corresponding to a set of coordinates:

```py
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3()
>>> address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.reverse("40.752067, -73.977578")
>>> print(address, latitude, longitude)
77 East 42nd Street, New York, NY 10017, USA 40.7520802 -73.9775683
```

--